# How can I select specific indexpath of a UICollectionView by default?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview

I want to highlight the specific cell of the UICollectionView by default.
However I can not do that.The code is below.
UIView(in the init method):

```
    let selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
    collectionView.selectItem(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: [])
```

UICollectionViewCell:

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {
        imageView.tintColor = isSelected ? UIColor.white : UIColor.red
    }
}
```

How can I select specific indexpath of a UICollectionView by default ?
If you need any other information to solve it, let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using a custom collectionViewcell? i.e. do u have a cell class

Comment: Exactly, I am using a customCollectionViewCell.

Comment: you can use ` [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];` and in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` you can have the selection logic as per the selected indexpath.

Comment: Also implement the collectionView delegate `override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}`

Comment: Sorry, I am using "Swift" not "Objective-C".

Comment: Edited for Swift.

Comment: I think that method is unrelated for this problem. Because that method's return is true by default.

Comment: is your `isSelected` method getting called?

Comment: Yes. isSelected: Bool {~} works.

Comment: try calling `didSelectItemAtIndexPath ` in your code.

Comment: I am not sure what you say...
I want to select specific item "by default".

Answer (score 2):

This only selects the first cell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //add here
    let selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
    collectionView.selectItem(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: [])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override this method

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
//you should set needed cells as selected here, or set it to deselected, because it is your responsibility now 
    var shouldSelect = false //or true
    cell.isSelected = shouldSelect
}
```

But in this case you should keep track of collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) method and reload collection while selection.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    collectionView.reloadData()
//or reload sections 
}
```

Comment: I can not implement your suggestion.
There is no method of "setSelected()".

Comment: Shouldn't you probably be using `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` instead of `reloadData`?

Comment: I added just `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
        collectionView.selectItem(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: [])
    }`
And then it works what I want.
Thanks for your help.